# Font opacity in QGIS

Tags: qgis, font, transparency-opacity

[image]I am setting this font to be only 30% opaque but the display and printing of the font is not changing.  What am I missing?

Comment: You're missing the buffer which you probably didn't set as opaque.

Comment: Yep! That is what I was missing Erik!